# How do conditional operators work in ruby

Tags: ruby, conditional-operator

Why doesn't this statement work?

```
1>2 ? puts "true" : puts "false"
```

[Here](http://romhack.wikia.com/wiki/Ruby_operators), I find that most ruby operators are like C with `()` parentheses having high priority. This code In C

```
1 > 2 ? printf("true") : printf("false")
```

executes successfully. Why is ruby code not working?

Comment: That statement works fine. What I'm guessing your problem is that you're executing it in a repl and you get `nil` back, which is fine because that's what `puts` return.

Comment: You wrote as if it works in C and the corresponding code in Ruby does not, but you omitted the parentheses in Ruby, not in C. You are comparing different things. The comparison does not make sense. And why is the priority of parentheses relevant when you do not have any parenthesis?

Comment: Because this statement works: `1 > 2 ? puts( "true" ) : puts( "false" )`. Ruby interpreter has a lot, but not too much syntactic sugar, and it avoids guessing the programmer's intentions. `>` has higher priority than ternary `? :`, but method calls need parenthesis when inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that ternary operator has lower priority than method argument. Ruby parses around the first instance of `puts` method up to:

```
puts "true"
```

and looks if there is another argument, which should be preceded by a comma if there is any. But you have a colon continuing:

```
 : puts "false"
```

which cases a syntax error.